# truck not shifting o/d blinking

Tags: ford, f-150, p1747, p0755, p0743

Trans codes are p1747 p0755 p0743. My o/d light is blinking and truck has loss of power. It will rev in drive, but in gear no power. It's a 2001 Ford F-150 4.6. I changed A and B solenoid, spark plugs, coils, fuel pump, fuel filter, and cleared codes. Started truck and codes came right back.

Answer (score 1):

Check your fuses. There is a power-train control module that may not be getting power.

If not check the wiring harness' from the transmission. There are several. Check for chaffing anywhere along the line.

Answer (score -1):

i found this

transmission turbine (overdrive) usually they crack and work for a while then just stop and keeps the truck from running smooth.

im guessing you checked fluid level and checked for leaks

dont know if this helps

Comment: Transmission overdrive is a physical gear. Not a turbine. You may be thinking of a torque converter.